# How to restrict users to go certain page before login in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, spring-mvc, web-applications

I am making simple web app project in maven spring mvc with hibernate .I have set all controllers and all work fine .Now I am gonna make restriction for users who haven't logged in .I don't wanna let them to go inside before logging in.And also After they log out ,they should be thrown out.How can I do this ?

Comment: Two words: Spring Security. Here is [doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/) and here are [tutorials](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/guides/html5//)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Servlet filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html). This is an object that can intercept HTTP requests targeted at your web application.

A servlet filter can intercept requests both for servlets, JSP's, HTML files or other static content, as illustrated in the diagram below.

[image]

In order to create a servlet filter you must implement the javax.servlet.Filter interface.

```
public class SimpleServletFilter implements Filter {

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
                         FilterChain filterChain)
    throws IOException, ServletException {

    }

    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

When a HTTP request arrives at your web application which the filter intercepts, the filter can inspect the request URI, the request parameters and the request headers, and based on that decide if it wants to block or forward the request to the target servlet, JSP etc.

It is the doFilter() method that does the interception. Here is a sample implementation:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
                     FilterChain filterChain)
throws IOException, ServletException {

    String myParam = request.getParameter("myParam");

    if(!"blockTheRequest".equals(myParam)){
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

Notice how the doFilter() method checks a request parameter, myParam, to see if it equals the string "blockTheRequest". If not, the request is forwarded to the target of the request, by calling the filterChain.doFilter() method. If this method is not called, the request is not forwarded, but just blocked.

The servlet filter above just ignores the request if the request parameter myParam equals "blockTheRequest". You can also write a different response back to the browser. Just use the ServletResponse object to do so, just like you would inside a servlet.

You need to configure the servlet filter in the web.xml file of your web application, before it works. Here is how you do that:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>myFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>servlets.SimpleServletFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>myFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.simple</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

With this configuration all requests with URL's ending in .simple will be intercepted by the servlet filter. All others will be left untouched.